# neo4j how can i explore explore multiple relation noeud

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With this query :

```
MATCH (p)<-[:ProcheMer]-(:Camping)<-[:Dispo]-(d:Dispo)<-[:Dispo]-(:Camping)-[:AccesMer]->(a)   
WHERE d.debut="2016-06-25" AND d.duree=7 
return count (a) as a, count(p) as p
```

I expected that p is > a, but the result is that a and p are equal, why ? cypher stops when it reaches the shortest way ? 
In generale how to maque multiple stats in multiple relation with the same query ?

Comment: Why would you expect `p > a`? You're matching paths between `p` and `a` so every path will include one of each - the counts will always be equal. Did you mean to count DISTINCT nodes? It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Thank-you for your comment. It's true there some thing not clear in my head :)
I want to do the count of ProcheMer relation and the count of AccesMer in the same query.

I know tha is possible to add boolean proprities to Camping node, and do a naive querty like: 
 
Match .. WITH CASE WHEN c.acccesMer=true then 1 else 0 as acccesMer, WITH CASE WHEN c.procheMer=true then 1 else 0 as procheMer return sum(procheMer) as procheMer, sum(acccesMer) as acccesMer

But i don't found a clear way to do the same thing drirectly with relation.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to count distinct rather than just count - otherwise you will count nodes twice when they take part in two relationships and the counts will always be equal.

Comment: Thanks again, finaly maybe I found, I use optionel Match like this MATCH (d:Dispo)-[dispo:Dispo]->(c:Camping) WHERE d.debut="2016-06-25" AND d.duree=7  Optional MATCH (c)-[procheMer:ProcheMer]->(p) Optional MATCH (c)-[accesMer:AccesMer]->() return count(procheMer), count(accesMer). But I think that is not the best optimisation because Opional MATCH is like joint in sql. Maybe make this kind of stats will be better with using WITH CASE WHEN with testing attibuts ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found, I use optionel Match like this :

MATCH (d:Dispo)-[dispo:Dispo]->(c:Camping) WHERE d.debut="2016-06-25" AND d.duree=7 Optional MATCH (c)-[procheMer:ProcheMer]->(p) Optional MATCH (c)-[accesMer:AccesMer]->() return count(procheMer), count(accesMer).

But I think that is not the best optimisation because Opional MATCH is like joint in sql  (that is true ?) and the result is more slowest than stats how can be made with postgres. Are there any other way ?